# How to save foreign key data using forms.py?

Tags: python, django

urls.py

```
...
path('restaurant/menu/', r_view.Menu, name='menu'),
...
```

menu.html

```
<form method="POST" id="menuForm" autocomplete="off" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group mb-4">
                {{ form.item|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-4">
                {{ form.itemImage|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-4">
                {{ form.price|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-4">
                {{ form.category|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="col-md-12 myBtn">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

views.py

```
def Menu(request, restaurantID):
    restaurant = get_object_or_404(Restaurant_Account, restaurantID=restaurantID) 
    form = MenuForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MenuForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.restaurant = restaurant
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, "Saved successfully!")
            return redirect('r_index')
            
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'restaurant/menu.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class MenuForm(forms.ModelForm):
    restaurantID = Restaurant_Account.objects.filter(restaurantID='restaurantID')
    item = forms.CharField(required=True)
    itemImage = forms.ImageField(required=False, label='Item image')
    price = forms.DecimalField(required=True)
    category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CATEGORY)
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ('item', 'itemImage', 'price', 'category')
```

models.py

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_restaurant = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    restaurantID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True, unique=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Menu(models.Model):
    menuID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    restaurantID = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant_Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    itemImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=[('', 'Choose category'),('Appetizer', 'Appetizer'),('Entree', 'Entree'),('Drink', 'Drink'),('Dessert', 'Dessert'), ('Side', 'Side')])
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

I'm new to Django.

I made a form for saving menu data. If the user fills the form and click the submit button every data should be saved in the Menu table. I have no idea how to save restaurantID, which is a foreign key that refers to the Restaurant table, automatically. (By automatically I mean without the user entering input) Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't need to do all these things, if you have made `restaurantID` a foreign key while defining the model that is `Menu`, django itself handles it.

Below code might work for you:

forms.py

```
class MenuForm(forms.ModelForm):
    item = forms.CharField(required=True)
    itemImage = forms.ImageField(required=False, label='Item image')
    price = forms.DecimalField(required=True)
    category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CATEGORY)
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ('item', 'itemImage', 'price', 'category')
```

views.py

```
def menu(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MenuForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Saved successfully!")
            return redirect('r_index')
    else:
        form=MenuForm()
    return render(request, 'restaurant/menu.html', {'form':form})
```

**optional:** You also don't need to write this line `menuID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` in `Menu` model, as django makes `id` column by default for `AutoField`.

#### Update:

Make your `models.py` in this way:

```
MY_CHOICES=[
('', 'Choose category'),
('Appetizer', 'Appetizer'),
('Entree', 'Entree'),
('Drink', 'Drink'),
('Dessert', 'Dessert'), 
('Side', 'Side')
    
]
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_restaurant = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True, unique=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Menu(models.Model):
    restaurant= models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    itemImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=MY_CHOICES)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

Remove your `AutoField`, django by default make `id` which is primary key.
Don't forget to run `makemigrations` and `migrate`, after doing this, if it still gives error, so comment your all `models` and then run.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I get this error when I try your code: 
IntegrityError at /restaurant/menu/
NOT NULL constraint failed: restaurant_menu.restaurantID_id

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you update your `models.py` file? i think for this, you should make `null=True` and then you need to run `migrations` and `migrate` commands in your `Restaurant` model which is not in your current `model.py`, update it.

Comment: Yes, I added null=True, so now the data is saved. But it does not pass restaurantID :/

Comment: Where to pass `RestaurantID`?

Comment: update your question with full `models.py` and tell that problem which you exactly facing?

Comment: So there's a column named RestaurantID in the Restaurant table and the restaurantID column in the Menu table refers to it.  So when the data is saved in the Menu table, using MenuForm, I would like RestaurantID from the Restaurant table to be passed and saved in the Menu table automatically. Also I updated my models.py!

Comment: if you see in `admin` interface, so it will always show you `record` not `id`, as django itself shows it, if you are going with  default database that is `sqlite`, then you'll be able to see id ,its the behavior of `sql`. But why you would like to pass `RestaurantID` and save one time again in `Menu` table, when you have already made it `foreign key`.